# mariadb Lead() function not accepting today's date as default parameter

Tags: mariadb, lead

I am trying to use Lead/Lag function in mysql. In lead and lag function there is option to use default value for last non existent row. see documentation below

[LEAD(expr [, N[, default]]) [null_treatment] over_clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead)

In above ***default*** value I want to use ***curdate()*** function but it is giving error

for example of my query is below

```
SELECT
  AdmissionNo,         
  PatientShiftDate,
  timestampdiff(DAY, PatientShiftDate,
      lead(PatientShiftDate, 1 , NOW()     )  
         over ( order by IPDBedAllocationNo)  )  as NoofStay 
FROM
  PatientBedShift
```

it is giving error

```
#42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' curdate()      )  over ( order by IPDBedAllocationNo)  )  as NoofStay  FROM...' at line 5
```

I want to calculate number days patient stayed in each room. It is returning null instead it should use curdate(), now() or current_timestamp() function so I can get correct number of days patient stayed in single query.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9930c9cda26a5ce4e78e6ff0020ade7c).

Comment: I have post real code and real error message